# trying to load data from url in R

Tags: html, r

so I want to load all the formatted data from this url:     https://data.mo.gov/Government-Administration/2011-State-Expenditures/nyk8-k9ti

into r so I can filter some of it out. I know how to filter it properly once I get it, but I can't get it "injected" into R properly.

I've seen many ways to pull the data if the url ends in ".txt" or ".csv", but if this url doesn't end in a filetype, the only way I know how to get it is to pull the html, but then I get... all the html.

there are several options to download the file as a .csv and inject it that way, but if I ever get good enough to do real work, I feel like I should know how to get this directly from the source.

The closest I've gotten is using the function:

`XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://data.mo.gov/Government-Administration/2011-State-Expenditures/nyk8-k9ti'`

but i get an error that says

`XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://data.mo.gov/Government-Administration/2011-State-Expenditures/nyk8-k9ti'`

so that doesn't work either :(.

If anyone could help me out or at least point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: In order to import the data directly from the website into R, I would investigate the "rvest" and "xml2" packages.  There should be plenty of examples on stackoverflow using these packages to import data into R.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question could be more precisely defined as "How to scrape data from website" rather than just simply loading data from an URL in R. Web scraping is totally another technique here. If you know some Python, I recommend you to take this [free course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-network-data) teaching you how to get access to data on website via Python. Or, you can try[this website](http://webscraper.io/) to get what you want, though, some advanced tools are not free. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complicated to scrape the data from the table but this website provides a convenient .json link file which you can access quite easily from R. The link **https://data.mo.gov/resource/nyk8-k9ti.json** can be found from Export -> SODA API.

```
library(rjson)
data <- fromJSON('https://data.mo.gov/resource/nyk8-k9ti.json')
```